# How to resolve a promise in an async function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, es6-promise

I have a lifecycle method componentDidMount that calls upon a recursive async method and I want the recursive function to return a promise after all the data has been fetched.

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    let response = await fetch(`${STORY_URL}${this.props.match.params.id}.json`);
    let result = await response.json();

    totalComments = result.descendants;

    await this.fetchComments(result.kids, MARGIN);

    this.setState({
      by: result.by,
      time: calculateTimeDifference(result.time)
    });
  }
```

and the function being called is

```
async fetchComments(comment, margin) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      comment.map(async commentId => {
        let response = await fetch(`${STORY_URL}${commentId}.json`);
        let result = await response.json();
        comments.push({
          by: result.by,
          margin: margin
        });

        if (comments.length === totalComments + 1)  resolve();

        if (result.kids !== undefined) this.fetchComments(result.kids, margin * 2);
      });
    });
  }
```

but the resolve method is not returning back to the componentDidMount before the setState. I checked by console logging. I don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: `fetch` returns a promise. so you may not need to put fetch inside a promise

Comment: how can i resolve use that promise to resolve await?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things. Use `Promise.all`:

```
 async fetchComments(comments, margin) {
   // Collect all the results here, otgerwise we would have to flatMap the promises which is more complicated
   const result = [];

   // Make sure that all comments were processed before returning
   await Promise.all( comments.map(async commentId => {
    const response = await fetch(`${STORY_URL}${commentId}.json`);
    const { kids, by } = await response.json();

    if(kids) {
       // Get all children and append them to the results, right after the children
       const children = await fetchComments(kids, margin * 2);
       result.push({ by, margin }, ...children);
    } else {
       // Otherwise just append this node
      result.push({ by, margin });    
    }   
  }));

  return result;
}
```

If the order matters, you have to flatten the result of `Promise.all`:

```
  async fetchComments(comments, margin) {
    const result = await Promise.all(comments.map( async commentID => {
      const response = await fetch(STORY_URL + commentID + ".json");
      const { by, kids } = await response.json();

      const result = [{ by, margin }];
      if(kids) result.push(... await fetchComments(kids, margin * 2));

      return result;
   }));

   // Flatten the results
   return [].concat(...result);
 }
```

Comment: the goal of this function is to push all the data into an array. Will this do the task?

Comment: @puskar now it does :)

Comment: This won't necessary push things into the `result` array in the same order as the `comments` were if that matters.

Comment: yes i also need the data to be pushed in the same order as they are fetched. I tried a different implementation before and it has the same issue

Comment: thanks Jonas you solution works. But i have the same problem the fetched data is not pushed in the same order that it is requested. is there any way to fix that?

Comment: @puskar yes that is possible, but its slightly more complicated.